# How to properly mock a controller that calls methods in different projects that implement dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, moq, xunit

I have a solution structured this way

```
>Solution
>>BusinessLogic.proj
>>DataAccessLayer.proj
>>Domain.proj
>>Web.proj
>>Test.proj
```

### Web.UserController

```
public class UserController
{
    private readonly IUserManager _userManager;

    public UserController(IUserManager userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public string GetUser()
    {
        return _userManager.GetAllUsers();
    }
}
```

### BusinessLogic.UserManager

```
public class UserManager : IUserManager
{
    private readonly IUserQueryMaster _userQueryMaster;

    public UserManager(IUserQueryMaster userQueryMaster)
    {
        _userQueryMaster = userQueryMaster;
    }
    public string GetAllUsers()
    {

        return _userQueryMaster.GetAllUsers();
    }
}
```

### DataAccesLayer.UserQueryMaster

```
public class UserQueryMaster : IUserQueryMaster
{
    private readonly CoreContext _CoreContext;

    public UserQueryMaster(CoreContext CoreContext)
    {
        _CoreContext = CoreContext;
    }

    public string GetAllUsers()
    {
        var res = _CoreContext.Users.ToList();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res, Formatting.Indented);
        return json;
    }
}
```

### Test

```
public class UnitTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void GetAllUsers()
    {
        //Arrange
        string JsonResult = @"{"//user1, user2... json format 
                                }";

        var mockIUserManager = new Mock<IUserManager>();
        UserController GetUserController = new UserController(mockIUserManager.Object);


        //Act
        var result = GetUserController.GetUser();

        //Assert
        Assert.Equal(JsonResult, result);
    }

}
```

Now when i debug the unit test, the execution cannot step into (F11) the class 'UserManager', resulting 'result' evaluation be 'null'. I suspect that this could happend be because i don't specify anywhere in my test that both UserManager and UserQueryMaster have their own needed services to access the data that i'm looking for.

My question is, how can i create my unit test with this 'nested dependency injection'?

Comment: You are mocking `IUserManager`, which means all of the nested services are not relevant. The only thing you're missing is setting up your mock to return something you can test. For example: `mockIUserManager.Setup(mum => mum.GetAllUsers()).Returns(JsonResult);`

Comment: You haven't mocked any of the methods of `IUserManager`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mocking `IUserManager`, which means all of the nested services are not relevant.

The only thing you're missing is setting up your mock to return something you can test. For example:

```
mockIUserManager.Setup(mum => mum.GetAllUsers()).Returns(JsonResult);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @DavidG. If I understand correctly, setting a mock this way is like telling: 'Ok, whenever my test use this method called GetAllUsers() should return the string 'JsonResult'. Why this would be valuable, if never calls the actual method GetAllUsers() outside the testing enviroment?. Later in the test I'm gonna code something like:  `var result = GetUserController.GetUser();` and `Assert.Equal(JsonResult, result);` and would be the same if i setup JsonResult and result to = 'asd'. My test would pass but would be worthless because never steps into the 'real implemntation'

Comment: The point of a unit test is to test only this unit of code. You should have another test that tests the implementation of the `GetAllUsers` method. For this unit test, you are only interested in the controller action.